# minimize Chi square function missing arguments

Tags: python, chi-squared, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have made a scatter plot of a x^4 function with certain parameters, I need to minimize the chi square function, but I keep getting the same error:, that I am missing some positional argument for the chisquared function, if I enter "a" and "b", I get an error saying a and b are undefined. I need to find Chi square minimum and the corresponding parameters a and b. below the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
Mystudentnumber=4420608
def f(x):
    a=float(str(Mystudentnumber)[-2:])/5
    b=float(str(Mystudentnumber)[-2:])/2
    return a*(x**4)+b


x=np.linspace(-15,15,30)  
plt.scatter(x,f(x), color='red')
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.title("Graph of function f(x)")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
xvalues=list(range(-15,16,1))
listofvalues=[]
error=[20,30,50,70,20,40,20,60,80,10,30,40,20,80,60,55,30,20,30,10,80,20,50,70,20,70,40,20,40,70]
i=-14
while i<=15:
    listofvalues.append(f(i))
    i+=1
print(listofvalues)
a=np.linspace(-10,10)
b=np.linspace(-10,10)
def chisquard(a,b):
    E=a*(x**4)+b 
    O=listofvalues
    err=error
    chisq=np.sum((((O-E)/err)**2))
    return chisq
x0=np.array([0,0])   
  
result =  opt.minimize(chisquard(print(a,b),b), x0)
print(result)
assert result.success==True
```

I tried playing around with the a and b values, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: `a` and `b` are only defined as local variables of function `f`. They don't exist outside of the function but on the other hand aren't actually needed for the optimization call. This is only one of multiple problems. You should begin with easier things to understand Python first.

Comment: The `print` function does not return anything.  If you need a debug print, do it on its own line.

Comment: But I do need the program to print the values for a and b for which the chi square is minimum